# Parse nested Python dict

Tags: python, json, dictionary, nested

I have a nested dictionary that I am trying to parse and do not seem to know how to access the third level items. Help is appreciated
Here is my dictionary

```
{
    "FunctionName": "RDSInstanctStart",
    "LastModified": "2018-03-24T07:19:56.792+0000",
    "MemorySize": 128,
    "Environment": {
        "Variables": {
            "DBInstanceName": "test1234"
        }
    },
    "Version": "$LATEST",
    "Role": "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxx:role/lambda-start-RDS",
    "Timeout": 3,
    "Runtime": "python2.7",
    "TracingConfig": {
        "Mode": "PassThrough"
    },
    "CodeSha256": "tBdB+UDA9qlONGb8dgruKc6Gc82gvYLQwdq432Z0118=",
    "Description": "",
    "VpcConfig": {
        "SubnetIds": [],
        "SecurityGroupIds": []
    },
    "CodeSize": 417,
    "FunctionArn": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:xxxxxxxx:function:RDSInstanctStart",
    "Handler": "lambda_function.lambda_handler"
}
```

I am trying to access the value for the key "Variables"
Here is my code so far:

```
try:           

 for evnt in funcResponse['Environment']['Variables']['DBInstanceName']:
            print (evnt[0])
except ClientError as e:
        print(e)
```

The result I get is

```
t
e
s
t
1
2
3
4
```

If I do not give the Index of the `envt` variable, I get a type error.

Comment: As a side not, you may be interested in something like [`dpath`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dpath) or one of its competitors to treat the nested collection as a flat collection with complex paths like `'Environment/Variables/DBInstanceName'` for keys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`funcResponse['Environment']['Variables']['DBInstanceName']` is a *single string*, but you are looping over it. Strings are sequences of single characters.

You'd get the same if you did: `for character in "test1234": print(character[0])` (and you can remove the `[0]` index too, since `character` is just as string with a single character in it).

Don't loop, just print:

```
evnt = funcResponse['Environment']['Variables']['DBInstanceName']
print(evnt)
```

If you wanted to print *all* environment variables, then you'd have to loop over the items of the `funcResponse['Environment']['Variables']` dictionary:

```
for name, value in funcResponse['Environment']['Variables'].items():
    print(name, value, sep=': ')
```

In any case, `funcResponse['Environment']['Variables']` is just a dictionary. Adding `['DBInstanceName']` to the end gives you the value for the `'DBInstanceName'` key.

Comment: Thank you Martijn. I understand now. Also thanks for the snippet to loop for all environment variables. At some point I will be doing that too.